# how to Set Ruby ENV using mutiple attributes in Chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am trying to set a Ruby ENV using two available node attributes by defining a path, but the standard string interpolation syntax is not working. Trying to achieve something like this:

```
ENV['CONFIGURATION_DIR'] = '/mnt/#{node[\'clientid\']}-#{node[\'environment\']}/conifg'
```

also tried

```
ENV['CONFIGURATION_DIR'] = '/mnt/node[\'clientid\']-node[\'environment\']/config'
```

is it possible to set a Ruby ENV using multiple attributes/data bag item values?

Comment: Was able to bypass this issue using the environment property which does accept the familiar syntax: environment "CONFIGURATION_DIR" => "/mnt/#{node['clientid']}-#{node['environment']}/config" .. Still would like a solution for the originally described scenario if anyone has one.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use double quotes if you want to use embedded variables.

```
bar = 'apple'

"foo #{bar}" # This will work.
=> "foo apple"

'foo #{bar}' # This will not work.
=> "foo #{bar}"
```

Comment: Thanks, based on your suggestion, I changed to: ENV['CTC_CONFIGURATION'] = "/mnt/#{node['ctc_clientid']}-#{node['ctc_environment']}/ctcConfiguration" but still getting nothing. If it helps, the standard way with one value is no quotes at all, for example ENV['HOME'] = node['home']

Comment: What is the value of that after you set it. Maybe you are not setting it to what you think you are.

Comment: It's blank. For testing I have an additional step that prints all my databag item values, attributes, and envs. That one is showing up as nothing.